# How to find non-greedy regular expression matching in JetBrains PhpStorm Search and Replace

Tags: regex, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, non-greedy

I'm using PhpStorm and I'd like to find shortest string between `{{` and `}}` by using Regex. An example is like this:

> `{{$ux['friend']['profile']['firstName']}} {{$ux['friend']['profile']['familyName']}}`

I tried this:

```
\$(.*)(\['.*'\])+
```

which finds like this

```
$ux['friend']['profile']['firstName']}} {{$ux['friend']['profile']['familyName']
```

but I want to make it non-greedy -- only find the string between each match of `{{` and `}}`  like

```
$ux['friend']['profile']['firstName']
```

Comment: As usual, just add `?` after `.*`. See [`\$.*?(?:\['.*?'\])+`](https://regex101.com/r/mS5xS4/1). Or a negated character clas variation: [`\$\w+(?:\['[^\]\[]*'\])+`](https://regex101.com/r/mS5xS4/2)

Comment: yep, it works, thanks,